# Android - GridLayout not responding to Weight properties

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm designing a fragment with many buttons, and instead of a combination of `LinearLayout`s or a `RelativeLayout`, I would like to use a `GridLayout`.

My app uses 21 as minimum API, so the GridLayout should support weight properties on children, but both the designer on API 21 and my phone (Samsung Galaxy S4, should use API 21) do not display anything when I use the weight property, and if I don't specify it, the Buttons on the right of the `GridLayout` are cut off the phone screen.

The `GridLayout` only behaves as it should on the designer when I set it to API 23. I've seen other posts on this matter but they all either redirect me to the `GridLayout` inside the support package, or give no solution that applies to my case.

Both the official Google documentation, and the internet in general state that this feature was introduced with API 21, and every piece of code I've found looks like mine, is there something I'm missing?

Here's the code to the `GridLayout`:

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="4"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="1"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="2"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="3"/>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="4"/>
```

Screenshots of the designer with the same code

[image: Designer, API 23]

[image: Designer, API 21]

Comment: In your API 21 screenshot, there isn't even an action bar or title bar visible.  That seems like a bigger problem if you expect them to be the same.

Comment: I think that's related to the theme, and it's a minor issue for me right now. As I said, it's not that the fragment doesn't display anything in API 21, I can get the buttons on if I remove all the width specifications, but then the ones on the right get cut off when I run the app and I can't find an explanation for that!